# Writing Latex doc with simultaneous update

Tags: latex

I wish to [write a cheat sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911516/how-to-make-cheat-sheets-in-latex) for physics/math course using Latex.
Generally I prefer to avoid using GUI, such as Lyx - I want to write the Latex source code by myself.
To do this effectively, I need that the resultant PDF file will be updated simultaneously while writing the Latex code, *without* writing the data to HDD for each update.
I thought of two methods to achieve this, but perhaps I'm missing something so I verify with you:

**Method #1 - Using Lyx:**
Probably Lyx has the right mechanism that updates the PDF in RAM.
I tried to edit the Latex source code but it *doesn't allow it*.

**Method #2 - Creating a directory in `/tmp` that has `ramfs` filesystem:**
The command `xetex` will create the PDF in RAM every 1 second or so.

Do you know a better method or an already available software that meets my requirements?

Using Ubuntu 14.04.